# Objective-C #import for classes

Tags: objective-c

I am seriously confused about the Objective-C #import.

I searched and found several tutorials saying that if I have lots of constraints like

```
#define val1 
#define val100
```

it's better to put all constraints in one file and import this file for reusing all values.

But i am still confused, I saw many code samples which #import all other files' headers in which there is is no

```
#define constraints
```

These two files are normal UIViewControllers, but their headers are imported.

```
#import viewcontroler1.h 
#import viewcontroler2.h
```

1. When can we simply create objects of classes why import them?
2. Where to import files in .h or .m?
3. What to import, the .h or the .m file in Objective-C?

I am seriously confused, please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify your question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm really understanding what you're asking for, but you should avoid importing header files in other header files, if you don't need to. Instead, `#import` the headers you need in the `.m` file and use the `@class`directive in your `.h` files instead.

From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html):

> The @class directive minimizes the amount of code seen by the compiler
>   and linker, and is therefore the simplest way to give a forward
>   declaration of a class name. Being simple, it avoids potential
>   problems that may come with importing files that import still other
>   files. For example, if one class declares a statically typed instance
>   variable of another class, and their two interface files import each
>   other, neither class may compile correctly.

Otherwise, you might be exposing your imported variables to more classes than you actually need. If you're importing your `constants.h` in `viewcontroler1.h`, any other class importing `viewcontroler1.h` will also have `constants.h`. Sometimes this might be what you need, but it usually isn't.

Hope that helped in some aspect...

Comment: if i want to switch between two views in iphone both viewcontrollers must be imported, but why? when i can create object and access, why #import.

Comment: You need to use `#import` to get access to properties and methods of your view controllers. All the `@class` directive does it to make the compiler aware of the view controller's type.

The class you're using to switch between the views probably needs to know about the view controllers' methods and properties to manage them.

I really recommend you to check out some of the Stanford iPhone programming classes on iTunesU and/or read a book or two to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1):

`#import` tells the compiler to (in simple terms) read the contents of the imported file before it goes any further.

If you import a file containing `#define` statements, then the macros in there will be available for use when writing code in that file.

If you import the .h file of a custom class, then the custom class will be available for you. Otherwise you can try to create the custom class and the compiler will have no idea what you are talking about.

In *theory*, you can write every line of code for your project in a single enormous file and never have to use `#import` at all (except for importing the UIKit and Foundation headers!). But that would be very silly.

Answer (score -1):

[I think you need to work through this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Developers-Library/dp/0321566157)

Comment: yes i have this book but its do not contain answer of my question