# Importing Confusion with objective C in header File

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone development and i have little bit Question.
My Question is When do we use @class and #import in .h (header )file.And if your answer is @class u can create instance but can not.. use its methods and by use of #import in .h file  we can access all method and variable of second class .Then My Question is 
if #import contains advantage then why many people used only @class in their .h file.

Please anybody have answer then reply asap.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please see my reply in this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966265/objective-c-import-for-classes/7966547#7966547

Comment: Dude,still confuse not clear with your answer

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904663/what-does-class-do-in-objective-c/3904757#3904757

Comment: Dude,still confuse not clear with your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're right with your assumption. 
As for advantages:
The @class directive is faster, since it only discloses the Name, and the Inheritance to the Namespace (e.g. the Header File). But #import loads everything, so it's slower and means more load on the system. If your Code is a library for another system, its pretty useful if the headerfiles only load the classname (@class)

For an example. You have the class A, and are importing a Headerfile B from a library. B itself wants to use C. If it imports all data in the B Headerfile, it gets bloated, because you would load it too when importing the headerfile into your class A. But it isn't necessary, that your class A knows what Class C is capable of, because only B is using it.

Comment: Dear Sir,First thanks for your quick and best answer but still confuse    in your last line  "if your Code is a library for another system, its pretty useful if the headerfiles only load the classname (@class)".what does means of "code is library for another system"

Comment: This does mean that if you are making a code such that you can use it as a library in other application.

Comment: yeah sorry i assume this wasn't very clear.
Sometimes you like to wrap your Code into a library (e.g. in ios development a static library)... or you use a library from the net, e.g. for http-connections. To use a library you import the headerfile, and if this headerfiles imports everything else, not only the class name, it gets pretty bloated for no reason at all. because you load stuff which doesn't need to be loaded. p.s. i edited my answer...

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever encountered cyclic imports,I suppose you are not.
The other answers are also correct but when it comes to cyclic imports the compiler gives error and you have to use @class instead of import.

quick example

```
//A.h
#import "B.h"

//B.h
#import "A.h"
```

In this case compiler will give you the error. So you have to use @class in one of the header files to remove cyclic import. It is true that @class is faster than #import but my projects doesn't have large amount of files that it would take hours to compile it :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, trying to be more clear, then. This is what you usually want:

1. Use `@class` in your `.h` file if the header file doesn't need access to anything in the class you're importing (i.e. it only needs to know that the class exists in order to compile).
2. Use `#import` in your `.m` file to get access to the imported class' properties and methods.

An example, where your class `Foo` needs to use another class you've created, `Bar`. `Bar` also has a custom initializer, `-initWithCustomValue:`.

**MyClass.h**

```
@class Bar

...

Bar _instanceVariable;
```

**MyClass.m**

```
#import "Bar.h"

...

_instanceVariable = [[Bar alloc] initWithCustomValue:1];
```

This would make sure that you're not exposing unnecessary code (i.e. the contents of `Bar`) to other classes that might be importing `MyClass.h`.

From the Apple docs:

> The @class directive minimizes the amount of code seen by the compiler
>   and linker, and is therefore the simplest way to give a forward
>   declaration of a class name. Being simple, it avoids potential
>   problems that may come with importing files that import still other
>   files. For example, if one class declares a statically typed instance
>   variable of another class, and their two interface files import each
>   other, neither class may compile correctly.